# php cURL instantiate remote class

Tags: php, curl

New to cURL and trying to load PHP file to instantiate a class with below code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$n = new Test_cURL();
```

I have cross checked and cURL is enable. Also cross check with that file from remote url is loading by

```
if (curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE) {
    return true;
} 
else {
    return false;
}
```

But when I am creating new instance it is giving me error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test_cURL' not found in
```

So how can I load a file allow to instantiate a class from remote?

## UPDATE

### All required details including sites URL and filename

```
<?php
/**
 * Remote Class
 * URL: http://localhost/php-lib/lib.php
 * filename: lib.php
 */
class Test_cURL
{
    public $msg;
    function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->msg = $message;
    }

    public function f_msg($add)
    {
        return $this->msg . ' is the property and ' . $add . ' is the parameter!';
    }
}


/**
 * cURL file on other site (could be other server)
 * URL: http://test-site/index.php
 * Filename: index.php
 */
$url = "http://localhost/php-lib/lib.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result=curl_exec($ch);
eval($result);

$n = new Test_cURL('loader message');
echo $n->f_msg('method message');

/**
 * Error message
 */
Fatal error: Class 'Test_cURL' not found in /var/www/html/test-site/index.php on line 26
```

Comment: ? your script calls the Test_cURL() class not the remote site. Imagine the chaos if you could trigger remote sites to lauch arbitary code which is what I think you are trying to do - though perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: curl is not a class - it's a set of functions: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: where is the class `class Test_cURL{}` ?

Comment: does `curl_exec()` returning class srting?

Comment: I am currently trying on localhost. So on my one site `http://localhost/test` is the `cURL` site and http://localhost/php-lib` is the library site where I want to call my class file `lib.php and there is a class `Test_cURL`

Comment: @CodeLover you have to echo your class as string

Comment: @NeelIon Do you mean echo`Test_cURL`instead of `new Test_cURL()` ??

Comment: @CodeLover no, echo code inside your lib.php file. when you are requesting to lib.php using cURL server executes the code inside lib.php but doesn't send any output. You have to echo your code to send output as string and curl will grab that string and eval() will evaluate the string as php code and run it inside index.php. Then you will be able to instantiate the class.

Comment: but than what if I want to send and receive the data as a parameters?

Comment: @CodeLover since your class included in index.php it will run as a part of index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` then use `file_put_contents` to store file locally.

`include` the file and instantiate the class.

Reference: http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/07/re-hardening-php-how-to-securely.html

Comment: `file_get_contents` will load the whole file content. Which I don't want. Because I don't want allow customers to get my core code but just the returning values from the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval()` to run your class and `CURLOPT_NOBODY` should be `false` so that it can return `string`.

**Curl code:**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '$url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

eval($result);



$n = new Test_cURL();

echo $n->name;
```

**Class Code:**

```
<?php

echo '
class Test_cURL{

public $name="rasmus lerdorf";

}';
```

Comment: Thanks for the code reference but it is giving the same error.

Comment: @CodeLover What is your curl url? and what is the error? The code is working fine in my localhost.

Comment: I have updated my question with all files and sites info. Please have a look